# use Curl to connect to dotnetnuke

Tags: curl, dotnetnuke

I have a dotnetnuke site where I would like to download some pages.  The site requires a login, which I have.  But I do not know how to get curl to pass in the right authentication.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get access to protected pages, you're going to need to pass an authentication cookie.  There isn't a way to pass in credentials directly (though there is if you're communicating with a service developed using the new [Services Framework](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Services-Framework-Security.aspx)).

So, I think you're going to need to login through a browser, and then copy the cookie that you get and pass that through in your curl request.